# Extracting information

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, search, 2016, excel

1. I have list of SharePoint site address in an excel workbook.
2. Need to extract all files (documents, excel spreadsheets, PDF documents) that contain list of specific keywords. The list of keywords will be listed in the above excel workbook.
3. The files found with specific keywords should be listed in the above workbook (or another workbook) with listing the SP site, Path to the document (that was found with the keyword) and the key word that was found.
4. The above search should be run under another user's access and not the person who is running the above search.
5. We are using 2016 SharePoint Version.

Is it possible to run the above script in Excel VB by making use of Sharepoint search option for faster retrieval of files?

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344910/get-the-content-of-a-sharepoint-folder-with-excel-vba and let me know if this helps in what youre looking to do.